# Define an attribute with a dataclass method in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

I have a class for bounding box coordinates that I would like to convert to a dataclass, but I cannot figure out how to set attributes using a class method like I would in a normal class. Here is the normal class:

```
class BBoxCoords:
    """Class for bounding box coordinates"""
    def __init__(self, top_left_x: float, top_left_y: float, bottom_right_x: float, bottom_right_y: float):
        self.top_left_x = top_left_x
        self.top_left_y = top_left_y
        self.bottom_right_x = bottom_right_x
        self.bottom_right_y = bottom_right_y
        self.height = self.get_height()

    def get_height(self) -> float:
        return self.bottom_right_y - self.top_left_y
```

and here is what I want it to do:

```
bb = BBoxCoords(1, 1, 5, 5)
bb.height
> 4
```

This is exactly what I want. I tried to do the same thing with a dataclass

```
from dataclasses import dataclass    

@dataclass
class BBoxCoords:
    """Class for bounding box coordinates"""
top_left_x: float
top_left_y: float
bottom_right_x: float
bottom_right_y: float
height = self.get_height()

def get_height(self) -> float:
    return self.bottom_right_y - self.top_left_y
```

but `self` isn't defined when I try to use it, so I get a NameError. What's the correct way of doing this with a dataclass? I know I could do

```
bb = BBoxCoords(1, 1, 5, 5)
bb.get_height()
> 4
```

but I would rather call an attribute than a method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For this sort of thing, you need `__post_init__`, which will run *after `__init__`*. Also, make sure `height` isn't set in `__init__`, so:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field   

@dataclass
class BBoxCoords:
    """Class for bounding box coordinates"""
    top_left_x: float
    top_left_y: float
    bottom_right_x: float
    bottom_right_y: float
    height: float = field(init=False)

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.height = self.get_height()

    def get_height(self) -> float:
        return self.bottom_right_y - self.top_left_y
```

In action:

```
In [1]: from dataclasses import dataclass, field
   ...:
   ...: @dataclass
   ...: class BBoxCoords:
   ...:     """Class for bounding box coordinates"""
   ...:     top_left_x: float
   ...:     top_left_y: float
   ...:     bottom_right_x: float
   ...:     bottom_right_y: float
   ...:     height: float = field(init=False)
   ...:
   ...:     def __post_init__(self):
   ...:         self.height = self.get_height()
   ...:
   ...:     def get_height(self) -> float:
   ...:         return self.bottom_right_y - self.top_left_y
   ...:

In [2]: BBoxCoords(1, 1, 5, 5)
Out[2]: BBoxCoords(top_left_x=1, top_left_y=1, bottom_right_x=5, bottom_right_y=5, height=4)
```